# Need to import local features.h

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, centos

In a Linux environment (CentOS7), I have a local `foo/features.h` that need to be imported in a basic `main.cpp`. The directory structure is like

```
./workspace/main.cpp
./foo/features.h
```

I'd like to import the file in `main.cpp` using

```
#include "features.h"
```

(instead of giving the relative path `../features.h`).

If I just perform from `workspace/`

```
gcc main.cpp -o m.out -I../foo
```

then other internal files like `/usr/include/stdio.h` fail to import `/usr/include/features.h` (because of the statement `#include <features.h>` in that file) and attempt to import my local `foo/features.h`.

I see the same behavior if I set `CPATH` instead of using `-I` for `gcc`. Is my only alternative to rename my `features.h`?

Comment: You could use `-I../` then `#include "foo/features.h"`

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thank you so much. That worked great.

Answer (score 0):

In order to include user created files, you need to put them between quotes and specify the path such as :

```c
#include "../foo/features.h"
```

`" "` is for user-created

`< >` is for system-wide librairies

So you don't need to overwrite the path with `-I`